# How to sign my JWT using Firebase private key to integrate with IdentityServer

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, asp.net-identity, jwt, identityserver3

I need to integrate my authentication server which is implemented using IdentityServer3 with Firebase services via JWT as described here:

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth

Here google said:

> Copy the new service account's public/private key pair JSON file to your
>   authentication server and sign the tokens with it.

Sample (Not exact) JSON file:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxx-c4004",
  "private_key_id": ".....",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE.....\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": ".....",
  "client_id": "....",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-.....com"
}
```

In my IdentityServer I have a resource owner client that generates JWT tokens but i signed the IdToken and the AccessToken by a .pfx file and i load it like below:

```
       /// <summary>
    /// Load the certificate that sign the Id or Jw token
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        return new X509Certificate2(
        Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ConfigMngr.GetAppSettingsValue<string>("IdSrv:SigningCertificatePath")), ConfigMngr.GetAppSettingsValue<string>("IdSrv:SigningCertificatePassword"));
    }
```

And then I assign it to the SigningCertificate property in IdentityServer OWIN configs.

I don't know how can i sign the token using the JSON file and also Google didn't describe much about that.

I created another method to exreact private key and send it as bytes to the X509Certificate2 constructor but it didn't works:

```
private static X509Certificate2 LoadJsonCert()
        {
            string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            var jsonFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin\\IdentityServer\\FirebaseCert\\mycert.json");

            FirebaseJsonCert firebaseJsonCert = null;
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonFile))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                firebaseJsonCert  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirebaseJsonCert>(json);
            }

            var header = String.Format("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----");
            var footer = String.Format("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");

            var start = firebaseJsonCert.private_key.IndexOf(header, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            if (start < 0)
                return null;

            start += header.Length;
            var end = firebaseJsonCert.private_key.IndexOf(footer, start, StringComparison.Ordinal) - start;

            if (end < 0)
                return null;

            byte[] certBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(firebaseJsonCert.private_key.Substring(start, end));

            return new X509Certificate2(certBuffer);

        }
```

It fires an exception:

> {"Cannot find the requested object.\r\n"}

With StackTrace:

> at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertBlobType(Byte[]
>   rawData)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[]
>   rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[]
>   rawData)    at ... (my code)

So please help?

Comment: Hi, I had to remove all "\n" characters from my public key as well as the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" lines.

Comment: I had to go through a longer path:
(1) call url from client_x509_cert_url and take from the response a value for the key from private_key_id
(2) stick together this value with the value for the private_key key and remove all "\\n" as @PierreNortje said
(3) it will be -----BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE----- followed by -----BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY-----
(4) load it from the code but by using X509Certificate2Collection.Import(bytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable); (so not using X509Certificate2 constructor)